# New child object not saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a Blog model and a BlogComment model. A Blog can have multiple BlogComments. The models are represented as follows:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid BlogGuid { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<BlogComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class BlogComment
{
    public Guid BlogCommentGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid BlogGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int ContactRef { get; set; }
    public ContactBase Contact { get; set; }
}
```

For the purposes of my project, I am getting blogs without tracking like so:

```
public Blog GetBlog(Guid guid)
{
   return context.Blogs.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(b => b.BlogGuid == guid);
}
```

Now on my blog page, users can add comments. So I create a new comment and call my repository `InsertOrUpdate` method to save the blog.

```
public void InsertOrUpdateBlog(Blog blog)
{
    var blogExists = GetBlog(blog.BlogGuid) != null;
    if (blogExists)
    {
        var contextBlog = context.Blogs.Local.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BlogGuid == blog.BlogGuid);
        if (contextBlog != null)
        {
            context.Entry(contextBlog).CurrentValues.SetValues(blog);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Blogs.Attach(blog);
            context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.Blogs.Add(blog);
    }
}
```

The blog exists but is not in the context because it's not being tracked at this point so it falls into the inner else block where I'm reattaching the blog and setting it's state to modified.

My blog service calls this function and then saves the changes:

```
public void InsertOrUpdateBlog(Blog blog)
{
    blogRepository.InsertOrUpdateBlog(blog);
    blogRepository.Save();

    string cacheKey = "Blog_" + blog.BlogGuid;
    cache.Remove(cacheKey);
}
```

`blogRepository.Save()` just calls `context.SaveChanges()`.

The problem I'm having is that the new comment is not being saved to the database and so when I go to call `GetBlog` again after I've saved, the new comment is not there. Any ideas?

Comment: You are not saving your changes. Last part of the function should be context.SaveChanges();

Comment: This happens outside of this function. Will add to question.

Comment: Is the context within `InsertOrUpdateBlog()` the same instance as within your `Save()` method, if not it won't work.  How are you creating the instance of your the dbContext within your blogRepository?

Comment: The new comment *is* there, but it's a comment on a *new* blog. By `context.Blogs.Add(blog)` you insert a new blog.

Comment: @Coulton It's the same context. I'm saving the context in the repository constructor and all methods reference this context.

Comment: @GertArnold the `context.Blogs.Add(blog)` line does not get hit in this case because the blog already exists.

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting:

`context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified;`

You mark **only** blog entity, not it's navigation properties.

If some navigation property has changed you need explicitly modify their state.

IMHO, adding comments deserves another method which accepts comment, sets it's state and saves.